# How to read and request XPath with HTML-coded special characters in it (Python, lxml, HTML)

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, screen-scraping

I am trying to parse millions of HTML-Documents with lxml.etree. I'm doing that by parsing the documents for h3 tags, checking the headlines for specific words and then parse the table which comes right after the specific headline tag. The ID attribute of the tag is the same as the html content, but with replacements of some special characters. My code to get the xpath I need looks like this:

```
    def build_headline_path(headline):
        headline = ' '.join(headline.split())
        replacements = [' ', '-', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü', 'ß', ',', '\n', '\r', '§', ':', '&']
        for replacement in replacements:
            headline = headline.replace(replacement, '_')
        headline_path = '//h3[contains(@id, "' + headline + '")]/following::table'
        return headline_path
```

And then in another function, I get the table via lxml like this:

```
    body = etree.HTML(html_document)
    table_needed = body.xpath(build_headline_path(headline))[0]
```

For most of the documents this procedure works fine, but about 0.06 percent of them contain strange HTML tags which look like this:

```
   <h3 class="b_teil" id="jp_Bilanz_zum_30.&nbsp;Juni_2018">Bilanz zum 30.&nbsp;Juni 2018</h3>
```

Or this:

```
    <h3 class="b_teil" id="jp_T_tigkeits_Gewin__und_Verlustrechnung_&#34;Finanzfonds&#34;_f_r_2017">Tätigkeits-Gewin- und Verlustrechnung "Finanzfonds" für 2017</h3>
```

As you can see, the ID attribute is generated from the text content. My problem is: How do I translate the special characters (in this case the non-breaking spaces and quotes) into a string which allows me to target the id attribute of the h3 element? I already tried addressing them like that, which didn't work:

```
    //h3[contains(@id, 'T_tigkeits_Gewin__und_Verlustrechnung_&#34;Finanzfonds&#34;_f_r_2017')]/following::table
    //h3[contains(@id, 'T_tigkeits_Gewin__und_Verlustrechnung_"Finanzfonds"_f_r_2017')]/following::table
```

Maybe someone could help me please with any idea? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I managed to solve my specific problem now by not looking into the ID attribute, but into the text content of the h3 element. But maybe someone has a similar problem who cannot switch to my specific solution, so I'll keep the question open.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this will fit into your whole code, but lxml.html just translates the strange characters automatically.

So for example:

```
import lxml.html as lh

strange = """
<doc>
<h3 class="b_teil" id="jp_Bilanz_zum_30.&nbsp;Juni_2018">Bilanz zum 30.&nbsp;Juni 2018</h3>
something
<h3 class="b_teil" id="jp_T_tigkeits_Gewin__und_Verlustrechnung_&#34;Finanzfonds&#34;_f_r_2017">Tätigkeits-Gewin- und Verlustrechnung "Finanzfonds" für 2017</h3>
something else
</doc>
"""

doc = lh.fromstring(strange)

for h in doc.xpath('//h3/@id'):
    print(h)
```

Output:

```
jp_Bilanz_zum_30. Juni_2018
jp_T_tigkeits_Gewin__und_Verlustrechnung_"Finanzfonds"_f_r_2017
```

The other problem you have is that one of these `id`s contains quotation marks, which you'll have to escape. For example, to search for the text of the second `h3` you'll need this:

```
doc.xpath("//h3[@id='jp_T_tigkeits_Gewin__und_Verlustrechnung_\"Finanzfonds\"_f_r_2017']/text()")[0]
```

Output:

```
'Tätigkeits-Gewin- und Verlustrechnung "Finanzfonds" für 2017'
```

Edit:

To extract the text elements from the `h3`:

```
for h in doc.xpath('//h3'):
    print(h.tail.strip())
```

Output:

```
something
something else
```

Comment: Thank you for taking my question! The desired output in this case would be "something" and "something else", not 'Tätigkeits-Gewin- und Verlustrechnung "Finanzfonds" für 2017'.. The thing is, I do not know the name of the id or the xpath in advance, I have to construct it myself for every document after finding a h3 element which contains some words I'm looking for (which is why I have the build-headline-path-function). Do you think it would help to add `headline = headline.replace('"', '\"')` in the build-function?

Comment: @nvkr_See edit. I don't know about the last sentence in the comment, since I don't know what `headline` is.

Comment: This is the html-text-content which is inside the <h3 class="b_teil" id="jp_ABCDEFG"> Tag

Answer (score 0):

I had once also problems with a Xpath with an escape character. I solved my problem with adding an r before the string.

```
r"X-Path"
```

With the r escape characters will be ignored.

But I had a fix Xpath, not a variable. So I'm not sure if this will help you.